# Laravel 7.0 php artisan route:list returns “Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\RolesController]] does not exist.”

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7.0 and I try to list all my routes with artisan route:list, but it fails and returns this :
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\RolesController] does not exist.

at C:\xampp\htdocs\Cleanpro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:811
807|
808|         try {
809|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
810|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
> 811|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 
0, $e);
812|         }
813|
814|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
815|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

1   [internal]:0
  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure} 
(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cleanpro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
  ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\API\RolesController does not exist")
```

**My api Routes**:

```
 Route::post('role','API\RolesController@store');
```

[image: screenshot of my project architect]

Comment: What is the namespace in the `RolesController.php` file? Make sure it is `App\Http\Controllers\API`

Comment: check your namespace in RoleController

Comment: yes it's : namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

Comment: Show  code of `RolesController.php`

Comment: this is my rolescontroller code : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/35/6/1598727301-coder.jpg

Comment: Do you have this `class RolesController extends Controller
{ }` in `RolesController.php`?

Comment: I think i forgot the "s" .. i have RoleController extends .....

Comment: The class name is incorrect. The `s` at the end of `Role` is missing. Change the class name to `RolesController`.

Comment: Controller name should be singular name by laravel convention. Change `RoleController` instead of `RolesController`. You should read naming laravel convention.

Comment: @Sobir there is no convention on that, people use both ... even the Laravel docs use both

Answer (score 0):

What is the namespace in the `RolesController.php` file? Make sure it is `App\Http\Controllers\API`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
```

Then, Make sure the class name is correct in the file: `RolesController`.
Make sure you are not missing any letter.

Comment: yes my name space is : namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

Comment: I've edited the answer. The class name is probably incorrect in the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Run this command**

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```